# Remove li from bottom of the list

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a list with some lis.

```
<ul>
        <li id="eup">....</li>
        <li id="1">a</li>
        <li id="2">b</li>
        <li id="3">c</li>
        <li id="4">d</li>
        <li id="5">e</li>
        <li id="ebtm">....</li>
    </ul>
```

I want to remove li from bottom starting from li with id=5 to li with id 3. 
    the li with id=ebm should not be deleted. 
    Any help for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) to get a hold of all elements between your start and end element:

```
var $start = $("#3");
var $end = $("#5");
$start.nextUntil($end).add($start).add($end).remove();
```

If you do not want the start and end elements themselves removed as well, simply don't include the corresponding `.add` calls.

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/defacer/tSVAK/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery **slice()** method.
[http://api.jquery.com/slice/](http://jQuery%20slice)

Like this:

```
$("ul li").slice(3, 6).remove();
```